# Updating Scene in Mayavi Python

Tags: python, wxpython, enthought, mayavi

I am relatively new to Python and even newer to Mayavi. I have a  following issue:  I have an application which can load a 3D image in csv format and displays it using Mayavi plot embedded in wxPython Panel.  This works fine the first time, but if I open another image, I cannot seem to be able to display it whatever I do. The scene seems to be either not updating, or updating and then reverting back to the old one.  Here is what I tried:

```
import numpy as np
from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance
from traitsui.api import View, Item
from mayavi.core.ui.api import SceneEditor, MlabSceneModel
from mayavi import mlab

class MayaviPanel(wx.Panel):
...
    self.mayavi_view = MayaviView(self.xyzi)
    self.control = self.mayavi_view.edit_traits(
                    parent=self,
                    kind='subpanel').control
    self.sizer.Clear()
    self.sizer.Add(self.control, 1, wx.EXPAND, wx.EXPAND, 5)
...

class MayaviView(HasTraits):

scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())
plt = None

# The layout of the panel created by Traits
view = View(Item('scene', editor=SceneEditor(), resizable=True,
                show_label=False),
                resizable=True)

def __init__(self, xyzi):
    HasTraits.__init__(self)
    self.xyzi = xyzi

    mlab.clf(figure=self.scene.mayavi_scene)
    mlab.surf(np.transpose(self.xyzi[0]), np.transpose(self.xyzi[1]),     
              self.xyzi[2], figure=self.scene.mayavi_scene)
```

Basically I call this every time I load image - I can see the new image loaded for a split second, but then it is replaced by the old image.

After this I tried to update the scene using a method like this:

```
def update(self, xyzi):
    self.plt.mlab_source.set(x=xyzi[0], y=xyzi[1], z=xyzi[2])
```

With this I didn't even see the new image loading.  Anyone has done something similar and can point me in the right direction ?